# What does @EnableBinding in Cloud Stream do in the back?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am currently using spring cloud stream. I'm using @EnableBinding annatotation. But I don't know what this doing in the back. When I looked at Springin's official site, I didn't get much. Can you please explain to me in detail?

I have one more question.

```
public interface Sink {
  String INPUT = "input";

  @Input(Sink.INPUT)
  SubscribableChannel input();
}


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class VoteRecordingSinkApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(VoteRecordingSinkApplication.class, args);
  }

  @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
  public void processVote(Vote vote) {
      votingService.recordVote(vote);
  }
}
```

Why does Spring need this interface?I just expected that we could just write streamlistener. What's going on in the back?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you didn't get much is because with 3.0.0 (Hoxton) we're moving away from annotation-based model in favor of functional and I've done as much as I could to remove as many references to both `EnableBinding` and `StreamListener` as I could from the new user guide. Our [release announcement](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/25/announcing-the-release-of-spring-cloud-stream-horsham-3-0-0-release) contains several links that dive deeper as to our motivations.

While you can get more information about `EnableBinding` in the [older guide](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.1.RELEASE/home.html), in the nutshell it sets up a bridge between the channels identified in the provided interface and external binder destinations (e.g., Kafka topic, Rabbit queue/exchange, etc).

But as I said, if you're just getting started with spring-cloud-stream, you don't need to use them